# How can I add two strings together as though they were variables?

Tags: c++

How can I add two strings together as though they were variables?
ex:

`std::cout<< a << b << std::endl;`

How can I do that only with two strings, `a` and `b`?

Comment: You ask for a name (*string*) but you read into an `int`. If you write `1` and `2` as input it works perfectly fine. You  have to replace the `int` with `std::string` and it will work.

Comment: The integer data type is not meant to hold char arrays.

Comment: I am very new to c++, how do I use the std::string

Comment: how can I do the `std::cout << a << b << std::endl;` line with strings

Comment: @PringlesT-rex perhaps you are looking for `a + b`? It is really hard to understand what you are actually asking for

Answer (score 1):

You can't store names which consist of a series of characters in integers. Use `std::string` instead.